# SQL Create column for same value on same row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I get same sku with different loc on the same column, I would like to add a column on the same row with the same value instead.

```
select 
    sku, loc, qty 
from 
    skuxloc 
where 
    loc <> 'STAGE' 
    and sku in (select sku 
                from skuxloc 
                where loc <> 'STAGE' and qty > 0
                group by sku
                having count(distinct loc) > 1)
order by 
    sku, loc
```

Output:

```
SKU              LOC    QTY
------------------------------
11704-01150N    08B17   1
11704-01150N    09B21   1
11704-01161N    04A16   1
11704-01161N    05B26   2
11704-01173N    09A22   2
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
SKU             LOC    QTY   Loc   QTY
---------------------------------------
11704-01150N    08B17   1    09B21  1
11704-01161N    04A16   1    05B26  2
11704-01173N    09A22   2
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: using oracle db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one for Oracle.
You didn't specify, but I assumed that if there was more than one duplicate loc for a sku, that you wanted to display them. E.g. if there are 3 loc entries for sku '11704-01150N', what should the output look like? Should it only display one of the duplicates, or both?

```
select 
    s1.sku, s1.loc, s1.qty, s2.loc, s2.qty 
from 
    skuxloc s1
left join skuxloc s2
    on s2.loc <> 'STAGE'
    and s2.qty > 0
    and s2.sku = s1.sku
    and s2.loc > s1.loc
where 
    s1.loc <> 'STAGE'
    and (s2.loc is not null 
            or (select count(1) from skuxloc s3 
                where s3.sku = s1.sku and s3.qty > 0 
                  and s3.loc <> 'STAGE') = 1)
order by 
    s1.sku, s1.loc;
```

Comment: should only display one duplicate

Answer (score 1):

for SQL-SERVER

DEMO AT http://rextester.com/live/EUYY95359

```
declare @myproducts table (SKU varchar(100),LOC varchar(20), qty integer)

insert into @myproducts
values 
('11704-01150N','08B17',   1),
('11704-01150N','09B21',   1),
('11704-01161N','04A16',   1),
('11704-01161N','05B26',   2),
('11704-01173N','09A22',   2)



select 
x.SKU,x.LOC,x.QTY,
y.LOC,y.QTY
from 
(
select 
SKU,LOC,QTY,
row_number() over (partition by SKU order by LOC) pos
from
@myproducts
) x
left outer join
(
select 
SKU,LOC,QTY,
row_number() over (partition by SKU order by LOC) pos
from
@myproducts
) y on y.SKU = x.SKU and y.pos = 2
where x.pos = 1
```